# Is it possible to use Akka Patterns.ask() where a classic actor asks a typed actor?

Tags: java, akka

Using Akka (Java) I am attempting to use the ask pattern (akka.pattern.Patterns.ask) where the asker is a classic actor and the askee is a typed actor. I am attempting something like this in the classic actor

```
Patterns.ask(Adapter.toClassic(typedActor), new TypedActor.Message(Adapter.toTyped(self())), timeout));
```

In the typed actor, the message is seen and replied to (e.g., like I show below), but the ask times out

```
msg.replyTo.tell(new Response());
```

Is this possible, and if so, could you help me with a simple example for how to do this in Java?

Comment: Just for the record, I removed an answer here where I foolishly confused the Patterns.ask with the old style ask ?. I just leapt to a conclusion because I've seen that problem several times with newbies. This appears to be more likely to be a probably with the adaption of the response, but I'd have to build out an test to be certain as I'm out of practice. Thanks to Levi for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Akka Classic's implementation of the ask pattern, `akka.pattern.Patterns.ask`.  This implementation is logically equivalent (there are some slight optimizations under the hood) to spawning an actor which schedules a timeout message to itself and then sending a message to the askee purporting to be from the spawned actor.  The spawned actor completes the future successfully if it gets a response before the timeout message or fails it with a timeout otherwise.

In

```java
Patterns.ask(Adapter.toClassic(typedActor), new TypedActor.Message(Adapter.toTyped(self())), timeout));
```

you're setting the classic actor which initiated the ask as the `replyTo` on the message, so the response from the typed actor goes to that classic actor, not to the actor which `ask` spawned, so that spawned actor will report that the ask timed out.  The typed behavior doesn't see the "return address" on the classic envelope.

The easiest fix is probably to use the Akka Typed ask pattern, `akka.actor.typed.javadsl.AskPattern.ask`, which would look something like:

```java
AskPattern.ask(
    typedActor,
    replyTo -> new TypedActor.Message(replyTo),
    timeout,
    Adapter.toTyped(getContext().getSystem()).scheduler()
)
```

The `replyTo -> new TypedActor.Message(replyTo)` injects the "reply-to" address into the request.

Note that while `Patterns.ask` returns a Scala future, this returns a Java `CompletionStage`: you'll most likely want to pipe the returned `CompletionStage` to the classic actor with

```
Patterns.pipe(csFromAsk, getContext().dispatcher()).to(self())
```

Note that blocking a thread while waiting for the `Future` from `Patterns.ask` or `CompletionStage` from `AskPattern.ask` is not a good idea and can create deadlock.

Comment: Thanks.  I now see where this approach is described in the akka docs, recommended when using the ask pattern from "outside an actor": https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#request-response-with-ask-from-outside-an-actor.  What are the pros/cons of doing it this way vs `akka.pattern.Patterns.askWithReplyTo()` as I described in the the answer I posted?

Comment: There's probably no great reason to prefer one over the other.  `AskPattern.ask` gives you a `CompletionStage` and takes a plain `Duration`, so no need to convert to/from more Scala-y classes.  OTOH, `AskPattern` forces you to get a scheduler (it's technically not needed in the implementation, that's a bit of future-proofing for if Akka Typed ever moves off of requiring Classic).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I landed on.  Short version: I used `Patterns.askWithReplyTo()` as I show below:

```
Patterns.askWithReplyTo(Adapter.toClassic(typedActorRef),
                        ref -> new TypedActor.Message("cat",Adapter.toTyped(ref)),
                        timeout)
```

This gives me access to the temporary actor created by the `ask` pattern, which I transform to a typed actor to allow the Typed actor to reply to this actor instead of directly to the asking actor.  This allows the Future to complete.

My complete classic actor example is below.  A Typed actor that handles `TypedActor.Message` and replies with a `TypedActor.Reply` to the replyTo argument is not shown.

```
package com.example;

import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.typed.javadsl.Adapter;
import akka.pattern.Patterns;
import akka.util.Timeout;
import scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters;

import java.time.Duration;

public class ClassicAskerActor extends AbstractActor {
    private final akka.actor.typed.ActorRef<TypedActor.Command> typedActorRef;
    static Props props() {
        return Props.create(ClassicAskerActor.class);
    }

    private ClassicAskerActor() {
        this.typedActorRef = Adapter.spawn(getContext().system(), TypedActor.create(), "typedActor");
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(String.class, this::onStringMessage)
                .build();
    }

    private void onStringMessage(String message) {
        Timeout timeout = Timeout.create(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        FutureConverters.toJava(Patterns.askWithReplyTo(Adapter.toClassic(typedActorRef),
                        ref -> new TypedActor.Message("cat",Adapter.toTyped(ref)),
                        timeout))
                .toCompletableFuture()
                .thenAccept(response -> {
                    System.out.println("Response received: " + ((TypedActor.Reply) response).value());
                })
                .exceptionally(ex -> {
                    System.out.println("Failed to get response: " + ex.getMessage());
                    return null;
                });
    }
}
```

I would be glad for feedback on what I am suggesting here.